# REGEX for first two characters from a set of values?

Tags: php, regex, typescript

I have a set of starting 2 alphabets as:

```
$arr = ['AB', 'DC', 'LF']
```

> **Problem:** I  need to make a regex (in **PHP** and **TypeSript**) that passes only those strings which starts with above values.

**Example:**

Valid:

```
ABwerty45^&*jk
ABwerrtty
LF%$^erftgt5234
```

Invalid:

```
TABYR56H
ab7877
Abtyu7
```

*Any help is appreciated.*

Comment: Can't you just get the first 2 letters and compare?

Comment: Get first two characters of string and check if they exist in given array.

Comment: `/^(AB|LF|DC).+$/g` for all or `^AB.+$`, `^LF.+$` and `^DC.+$` for individual

Answer (score 1):

You could [**join()**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) the array and compose a regex with an alternation like this:

```
<?php

$strings = <<<DATA
ABwerty45^&*jk
ABwerrtty
LF%$^erftgt5234

TABYR56H
ab7877
Abtyu7
DATA;

$arr = ['AB', 'DC', 'LF'];
$regex = '~^(?:' . join('|', $arr) . ').*~m';

if (preg_match_all($regex, $strings, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches);
}
?>
```

---

Which yields

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ABwerty45^&*jk
            [1] => ABwerrtty
            [2] => LF%$^erftgt5234
        )

)
```

---

Basically, this says:

```
^             # match the start of the string
(?:AB|DC|LF)  # AB or DC or LF
.*            # 0+ characters in that line
```

Comment: How About using a static regex if possible?

Comment: @AbhijitSrivastava: See the lower part of the answer, you can use the static variant.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a regex you could check if the first 2 characters are present in the array:

```
$arr = ['AB', 'DC', 'LF'];
if (in_array(substr("ABwerty45^&*jk",0, 2), $arr)) {
    // ...
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/M5I2T)

```js
const strings = [
  "ABwerty45^&*jk",
  "ABwerrtty",
  "LF%$^erftgt5234",
  "TABYR56H",
  "ab7877",
  "Abtyu7"
];
const arr = ['AB', 'DC', 'LF'];

strings.forEach((s) => {
  let match = arr.includes(s.substring(0, 2));
  match ? console.log("Match : ", s) : console.log("No match: ", s);
});
```